# Glassfish throws com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: java, jax-ws, glassfish-3

I have deployed jax-ws web service into glassfish 3.1.My client request for the service method which returns 5000 to 10000 list of objects.In between processing server throws ClientTransportException with following stack-trace.

```
com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 500: Internal Server Error
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:314)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:265)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:184)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:109)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:641)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:600)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:585)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:482)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:323)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:161)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:113)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:93)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:144)
at $Proxy190.webservicemethodcall(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I try to monitor the glassfish request but it show errorcount 1 in request statistics but it don't provide me any proper reason of errorcount.
It has been observed in multiple test,i got the client Transport at client but at server the method thread separately working properly up to last line.It don't aware of broken connection.
I think that the connection is broken so thread can not return the response at last.

Note : If return response is small like up to 3000 objects it works fine.But i don't thing it is matter of size.It is matter of timeout.My request connection is broken before creating responce

Please help me

Comment: not getting same error on jetty server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try any combination of the following:

1. While your request is running, run a continuous ping from the client. You should see a break in the pinging (or an increase in TTL at least to confirm the theory)
2. Set the following JVM property for a dump of the HTTP message exchange between server and client

   ```
   -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true
   ```
3. Try [TCPMon](http://technonstop.com/tcpmon-tutorial)
4. Implement a JAX-WS [SOAP Handler](http://jax-ws.java.net/articles/handlers_introduction.html) to capture the exact moment when the pipe runs dry. This might have the extra benefit of throwing a meaningful exception when the handler attempts to log a message and gets burnt by the absent message

Answer (score 1):

A HTTP 500 means Internal Server Error, which is no fault of your client.  Something about your request is failing on the server.  You should look there for more info.  Your client side stack trace isn't going to help.

Comment: Look in the server logs.  You should see a stack trace there.

Comment: @MayurB- Sorry, I think I am answering the question.  You are welcome to worry over the client stack trace all you want, but that is not where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

If your logging policy is not clearly defined, your exception might be silently swallowed on server side.

I would try to add a try/catch block to detect where this happens (and eventually remove it later if you improve your logging strategy)

```
public returnType yourMethod(){
    try {
    .... all your code
    }catch (final Throwable t) {
      log.error("Failed to wait for device update: " + t.getMessage());
      //eventually re-throw the error
    }
}
```